# Laravel 5 | Integrity constraint violation: 1452

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, foreign-keys, laravel-5

When i try to Create Message with more than one tag :

Controller : Message_cont

```
public function store() {
    $tags = $request->input('tags');
    $message = \Auth::User()->messages()->create(request::all());
    $message->tags()->attach($tags);
}
```

Model : Tags

```
public function messages() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\messages');
}
```

I Get MySQL insertion Error as :

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or 
update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 
(`homestead`.`messages_tags`, CONSTRAINT `messages_tags_tags_id_foreign` 
FOREIGN KEY (`tags_id`) REFERENCES `tags` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: 
insert into `messages_tags` (`created_at`, `messages_id`, `tags_id`, 
`updated_at`) values (2016-02-15 04:44:14, 1, 3, 2016-02-15 04:44:14), 
(2016-02-15 04:44:14, 2, 3, 2016-02-15 04:44:14))
```

What is Wrong with my Code ?

Comment: Do you have entry in your `tags` table with id 3?

Comment: Oooh.....Yeah....
Thank Q....!

Comment: What're there id's ?

Comment: Ya i just forget abt that order...
Actually, that id represents the "message_id"...
I have only 2 tags...

Comment: You are trying to associate an id of `3` in your `messages_tags` table. Make sure you have that id `3` in your `tags` table.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to associate an id of `3` in your `messages_tags` table and you don't have such as entry on your `tags` table. Thats why you are getting the integrity violation error.

Make sure you have that id `3` in your `tags` table.

Comment: Thank Q...
Already i find that issue in my order of insertion.
Now its works fine....!